# tostring() is implicitly called... how?

Tags: java, tostring, object-to-string

In the following code, how is `toString()` is implicitly called?

```
class Payload {
    private int weight;
    public Payload (int w) {
        weight = w; 
    }
    public void setWeight(int w) {
        weight = w; 
    }
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(weight); 
    }
}

public class testpayload {
    static void changePayload(Payload p) {
        p.setWeight(420);
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Payload p = new Payload(200);
        p.setWeight(1024);
        changePayload(p);
        System.out.println("p is " + p);
    }
}
```

Comment: *Please* take more care to format your code - this looks horrible at the moment. (And include text text in your question, not just a dump of code.)

Comment: I've formatted your code. Please use the formatter in your text editor / IDE before posting. Also, comments in code are as important as land is to a Magic: The Gathering deck. Please explain what your code does; it helps us helping you.

Answer (score 9):

This line:

```
System.out.println("p is " + p);
```

uses string concatenation, which is specified in [section 15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) of the JLS, starting with:

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

[Section 5.1.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11) has:

> Any type may be converted to type `String` by string conversion.
>
> ...
>
> Now only reference values need to be considered:
>
> - If the reference is `null`, it is converted to the string `"null"` (four ASCII characters n, u, l, l).
> - Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the `toString` method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the result of invoking the `toString` method is `null`, then the string `"null"` is used instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `"p is " + p`, which effectively is compiled to

```
new StringBuffer("p is").append(p)
```

This code calls `p.toString()` within `.append()` as `p` is `Object`.

> Specified by:
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#append(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a language feature which is available for free. See [Concatenating strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) section:

> Such a concatenation can be a mixture of any objects. For each object that is not a String, its toString() method is called to convert it to a String.